# C# WebBrowser - How to fill in TextArea DOM?

Tags: c#, .net, html, browser

I don't know how to fill in the text to textarea object on an HTML page.

I tried these:

```
//1
obj.InnerHtml = "mytext"
//2
obj.Focus();
Sendkeys.SendWait("MyText");
//3
obj.InnerText = "mytext";
```

But neither of them work.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting `obj` ? seems to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the element ID, you can use this:

```
webBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById("Element_ID_Here").InnerHtml = "TEXT HERE";
```